# EF Core timeout with using view

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I query view that contain SELECT statemant with join like this: `left join (select top (1) with ties`, it can take a lot of time and sometimes bring timeout exception on container. Query can processed more then 30 seconds on ef core, while same query direct executed on sql take only few seconds.
Please help resolve this problem.

View configured like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>()
            .ToView("VW_NAME")
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

When I remove `left join (select top (1) with ties`, it executing fast on EF Core.

View look like this (this is my real view with changed fields names):

```sql
SELECT
    Field1 = p.[Field1],
    Field2 = p.[Field2],
    Field3 = p.[Field3],
    Field4 = ISNULL(vf.FieldA, ISNULL(ad.FieldB, ISNULL(p.FieldC, FieldD)))
FROM
    dbo.Table p WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[TableVF] vf WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON vf.Id = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES  Id, FieldB
        FROM dbo.[TableAD] WITH(NOLOCK)
        ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY modified DESC)
    ) ad
        ON p.Id = ad.Id
```

From C# this called like:

```cs
var data = await _db.ViewsDatas.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id== request.Id);
```

or in query like this:

```cs
var data = from vacancy in _context.SomeTable1.Include(v => v.Skill)
    join offer in _context.SomeTable2.Include(o => o.Employee)
        on vacancy.Id equals offer.Id
    join viewData in _context.ViewsData
        on offer.Id equals viewData.Id  //problem view
    select new { Vacancy = vacancy, Offer = offer, ViewsData = viewData, Ext = ext };
```

Comment: That's because `left join (select top (1) with ties` is executing for each and every row you are joining to.  Find another way to do whatever it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: Without seeing neither the view nor the LINQ-to-EF query it is difficult to give you a precise answer. Is this a XY problem? See; [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , added example of view

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the select list. This produces the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`. Is this your real view? And how is this view called from C#?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, comma at the end is a typo. This is my real view with changed fields names. From C# this called like:  `var data = await _db.ViewsDatas.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id== request.Id);`  
or in query  like this:  
`var data =
from vacancy in _context.SomeTable1.Include(v => v.Skill)
join offer in _context.SomeTable2.Include(o => o.Employee) on vacancy.Id equals offer.Id
join viewData in _context.ViewsData on offer.Id equals viewData.Id //problem view

select new { Vacancy = vacancy, Offer = offer, ViewsData = viewData, Ext = ext };`

Comment: Adding `NOLOCK` doesn't mean `go fast` or `don't take locks`. It means `ignore other locks, read uncommited, dirty and duplicate data while taking a Schema lock on the entire table and randomly throw errors`. It won't fix any performance problems, it will make things worse